# How to show the text of a property instead of the ID in Razor MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, razor, drop-down-menu

Maybe this is very simple to do but I can't find the good words when I search on stackoverflow or on google.

I have a model and this model contains a "Country" property that is a integer. When I am in the Edit view, this property is used this way and it work well.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries, "IDCountry", "Name"))
```

In the Details view, I only want to show the name of the country, but I don't know how! Right now, I'm doing this but it only show the ID and I can't find a way to give him the List so it use it as a datasource or something like that to show "Canada" instead of 42.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can this be achieved?

By using a view model of course:

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

and then you would populate this view model in the controller action that is supposed to render your Display view:

```
public ActionResult Display(int id)
{
    Country country = ... go and fetch from your db the corresponding country from the id

    // Now build a view model:
    var model = new CountryViewModel();
    model.CountryId = country.Id;
    model.CountryName = country.Name;

    // and pass the view model to the view for displaying purposes
    return View(model);
}
```

Now your view will be strongly typed to the view model of course:

```
@model CountryViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CountryName)
```

So as you can see in ASP.NET MVC you should always be working with view models. Think in terms of what information you need to work with in a given view and the first thing you should do is define a view model. Then it's the responsibility of the controller action that is serving the view to populate the view model. Where the values of this view model are coming from doesn't really matter. Think of the view model as a single point of aggregation of many data sources.

As far as the views are concerned, they should be as dumb as possible. Simply work with what's available in the view model.

Comment: I understand the concept behind your answer but the problem is that my view is not just showing a country. It's a view based on a Profile model so it contains a lot of other property. The Profile model is also linked to the database via EntityFramework so I can't just remove the Country property and replace it with a CountryViewModel inside the Profile model because it will break everything. What do I do?

Comment: `What do I do?` - use a view model of course. Add whatever properties and information you need to this view model. You said that you need a Profile information, right? Great, go ahead: `public Profile Profile { get; set; }` and then populate this property in the controller action. Just make sure you rename the `CountryViewModel` class to something else as this name doesn't seem appropriate if it contains Profile information about users. So no matter what you ask me, my answer will always be the same: **use a view model**. That's the only correct way to do ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You could use any other techniques such as `ViewBag` or whatever if you want but make sure you never quote me as having recommended anything like that. At the contrary in my opinion ViewData/ViewBag is the worst thing that happened to ASP.NET MVC.