# How can I set my drop down menu to return text value instead of its ID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, razor-pages

I am fairly new to coding with razor pages and .NET core. This may be an easy problem to solve, but I cannot find the resources to help me. The closest I have found is this link, but I either don't understand it or don't think it applies because I am trying to avoid using a controller as best I can since I am using Razor pages.

[How to show the text of a property instead of the ID in Razor MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305818/how-to-show-the-text-of-a-property-instead-of-the-id-in-razor-mvc-3)

I have one page that allows you to create a new entry for a new employee. I have another page that allows you to create a task and assign it to an employee from that list using a drop-down menu. This is my code to query the info for the drop-down menu, which works as expected.

```
    public class EmployeeNamePageModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> EmployeeNameSL { get; set; }

        public void PopulateEmployeesDropDownList(ServiceContext _context)
         {
            EmployeeNameSL = _context.Employees_Informations.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.ID.ToString(),
                Text = a.employeename
            }).ToList();
         }
     }
```

This is the code on my create page for the jobs. When "Create" is clicked, as expected a new page opens where I input my information and choose an employee from the drop-down.

```
    public class CreateModel : EmployeeNamePageModel
    {
        private readonly Template.Data.ServiceContext _context;

        public CreateModel(Template.Data.ServiceContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            PopulateEmployeesDropDownList(_context);
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Service_Request_Information Service_Request_Information { get; set; }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Service_Request_Informations.Add(Service_Request_Information);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

    }
```

However, after I save the page and it is indexed, rather than the name of the employee, I see the primary ID instead. My work around right now is simply to not query for the ID in the PopulateEmployeesDropDownList function and instead only query for the employee name. However, I will eventually need to know the ID of the selected employee so I can later use it in a function to email that person.

So, how do I get the name of the person to show up on the Index page instead of the ID of that person? The answer in the link above says to use a view model, but he is using a controller if I understand correctly. With razor pages, it is my understanding that controllers are not necessary; therefore, I would like to not use them if I can help it.

EDIT: This is my code to view the drop-down menu in the create page. The drop-down view is fine, it is when it is indexed after being submitted that that field is saved as the ID.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Service_Request_Information.AssignedTech" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Service_Request_Information.AssignedTech" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="Model.EmployeeNameSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Service_Request_Information.AssignedTech" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: How do you display the drop-down in your view ?

Comment: Updated the post to include the view code from the create page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I get the name of the person to show up on the Index page instead of the ID of that person?

You populate the `Value` of dropdown `<option>` with employee's ID `a.ID.ToString()`, so the selected value (ID) would be posted in form data and bound to the specified model's property, and you got the ID of the employee instead of the `Text` of selected `<option>`.

To achieve your requirement, you can try following approach:

Add additional property `SelectedEmployeeName` in model class

```
public class Service_Request_Information
{
    public string AssignedTech { get; set; }

    public string SelectedEmployeeName { get; set; }

    //other properties
}
```

Use a hidden field to save name of selected employee

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Service_Request_Information.AssignedTech" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Service_Request_Information.AssignedTech" class="form-control"
            asp-items="Model.EmployeeNameSL" onchange="ddl_change_func(this);">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    </select>

    <input id="selected_val" type="hidden" name="Service_Request_Information.SelectedEmployeeName" value="" />

    <span asp-validation-for="Service_Request_Information.AssignedTech" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Set value of hidden field with selected option text

```
<script>
    function ddl_change_func(el) {
        //code logic here...

        //set value of hidden field with selected option text
        var ename = $(el).find("option:selected").text();
        $("#selected_val").val(ename);
    }
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This got me so much further along. `SelectedEmployeeName` had the text name, but `AssignedTech` was still the value being displayed in the index page. The only thing missing was I needed to set `AssignedTech` to `SelectedEmployee` in the `OnPostAsync` section.